# PHP page as a function/process module

Tags: php, process, module

First of all, this is my first post in Stack Overflow and I'm trying to learn PHP/MySql for a personal project that I'm working on. I think I will be spending alot of time on here to ask heaps of questions, so forgive me if I ask too many questions that you may find trivial.

**On with the question.**

I'm using a combination of ajax and PHP to process server side scripts. What I want to do is have a PHP module that will accept input, process something, and provide output. Much like a function.

What I'm trying to wrap my head around is how can I make PHP like a black box process module, like a function, rather than a page.

As an example, I have a login.html page which uses AJAX to send request to a login.php page. The login.php accepts the input, process the input, and output a json object which tells the calling page if it is successful, and if not will list the errors that it encountered along the way.

Here lies the issue. I don't want user to be able to go to login.php directly. In fact, I don't even want login.php to be visible to the public. The login.php is only a process, so if you go to it, it will be blank. This doesn't seem like a good practice to let users see a blank page.

I thought about putting the login.php outside the public folder, but this would mean that ajax won't be able to make a request to it either.

To get around this I have the login.html sit within the login.php. It will make a request to itself, then based on the type of request, the php will perform different things. This will resolve the "blank page" issue. But I can't help wonder if there is a way to make a standalone PHP module without having to make it work like a page also.

Any thoughts into this will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If AJAX can call the page, the client can access the page; JavaScript is executed client-side, meaning it's in their hands. It's easy to make PHP pages "act" like functions (look into MVC frameworks, such as cakePHP and LithiumPHP), but if they're accessible they're accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an AJAX can request the page, then any user will be able to navigate to the page with their browser. You really shouldn't be concerned with this, because unless they snoop around they won't happen upon the PHP page. If you want a little bit of verification that the request was made by AJAX you can [look for the `X-Requested-With` header](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax), but this doesn't always work because every browser doesn't send this:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    // Ajax Request
} else {
    // Not AJAX, redirect to login page
    header('Location: login.html');
    exit();
}
```

To make this work reliably on every browser, you'll need to set this header on the clientside:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
```

However this is still not fullproof because anyone can send a header with a program like Tamperdata, but this should be good enough to prevent the lazy snoop. Again though, allowing users to see this page (if they snoop) won't be a huge problem. It's not going to create a security vulnerability and on the off chance that a user stumbles upon the `login.php` page, they'll be redirected back to `login.html`.

Comment: Regarding the `X-Requested-With` header, it's also worth pointing out that any/all HTTP headers can be spoofed too (easily).

Comment: @newfurniturey Yes, that was in the edit I added while you were writing your comment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the goal is to not have any page that an unsuspecting user could navigate to and get nothing (not even a 404) - not to provide real security against attackers.

Comment: @Brilliand And that's why if the request didn't appear to be from ajax, the user would be redirected back to the login page.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I see now that it is the problem with AJAX... using that will mean I forego any privacy, because the nature of ajax is a public request.

Comment: @HengLim What concerns do you have (beyond the blank page, which you could easily turn into a redirection)? It seems to me like it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It wasn't a concern of security. It was more a question of good practice. I didn't understand the nature of AJAX which I needed clarification, which you provided. Seems like a redirection would need to be in place for every public php files that are visible to ajax.

Comment: @HengLim You could also consider merging the AJAX request processor and login page into one file. This way you wouldn't need to redirect and users without ajax would gracefully fall back to sending the request to the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you send an AJAX request to can also be navigated to directly, by the nature of AJAX.  All you can do is not provide the user with any indication that that page exists.

You do have the option of having one PHP file call another, via [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).  That way, you can have the request to login.php change behavior based on the request, but have the login handling actually processed by a file that isn't publicly accessible:

```
if($_POST) {include '../login-handler.php'; die();}
```

Comment: As per my other comment. I know now that the issue lies with Ajax public request. Thanks. But you bring up a valid point about including function within PHP from outside the public folder. I'm thinking of having one PHP request handler that will route requests to other PHP functions outside the public folder.

Comment: The PHP requester handler's role will be to validate whether the forms that have been submitted is the correct form and if so it calls the relevant function.